# cache interaction steps and read cycles

Tags: caching, assembly, mips

I'm struggling to fully grasp how caches work. 
Let's say I have a L1 cache and L2 cache.

1. The CPU (main memory) gives the L1 controller the memory address.
2. L1 cache controller determines cache set, requested cache tag, and block offset
3. L1 cache circuits check if the requested tag is in set
4. Can't find L1 cache tag match.

Does #2 happen here or after L1 sends L2 the memory address?

On read times if L1 takes x cycles, L2 takes y cycles, and main memory takes z cycles. Basically if the above steps happen and then L2 finds a cache tag match and sends it back to L1 who sends it to main, how many cycles does it take? When L1 returns it to the CPU does that count as a read cycle or not?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

L1 might be in the processor but the process is still the same.  The processor performs a read lets say, the address and read/control signals go out.  From the address the L1 cache looks up the tag and determines hit/miss.  If it is a hit it returns the information, if it misses then the L1 needs to go out on its address bus, adjust the address to align it to the cache line size and address alignment.  The L2 does the same thing the L1 does at a high level, address turns into a tag turns into a hit/miss, if a miss then it puts the aligned/sized cache line fetch on its external address bus, this repeats until you hit something that answers (DRAM, peripheral, etc).  When the L2 responds it sends the line back to L1, L1 per the rules of the design/settings save the line and then return to the processor the data/length of what it asked for.  For that moment, depending design and settings the L1 and L2 contain the same data, ideally the L1 contains all the data in L2, L2 contains all the L1 data plus some.  Granted non-cacheable requests should pass through so you may have a L2 hit that results in L1 not storing the data.  Also based on the design a non-cacheable request may pass through to the other side of L1 and/or L2 in the original processor size/shape rather than being aligned and sized to a cache line.